# How to read resources csv file

Tags: c#, file, resources

I used to use csv file in my application

here is the original code

```
        string csvFile = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\data\" + Scheme + ".csv"
        DataTable dt = ReadCSV(csvFile);
        dgv.DataSource = dt;
```

now I want to put csv file as embedded resource

I tried this. but It does not work

```
        string csvFile = System.Resources.MyFile; //This is error
        DataTable dt = ReadCSV(csvFile);
        dgv.DataSource = dt;
```

I wonder how to get the code running correctly?

Comment: do you have the generated resources class file?

Comment: @DanielA.White I am not sure what that is?

Comment: I used this line using System.Resources;

Comment: What error do you get? How do you insert the file into the project's resources? Perhaps you add the file to the project's tree? Go to Project -> [yourProject] Properties -> Resources and drop that file their.

Comment: @dr.null i did and trying to read these files now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the file has been added in the menu Project/Properties/Resources like @dr.null said, you have to click on the item's name in the solution explorer so that you can set Action property to "build-in resource".

Then, use something like that:

```
using System.Reflection;

var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var resourceName = "assembly_name.Resources.yourFile.csv";
var lines = ReadLines(() => Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName), Encoding.UTF8).ToList();
```

Where:

```
        public IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(Func<Stream> streamProvider, Encoding encoding)
        {
            using (var stream = streamProvider())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    yield return line;
                }
            }
        }
```

You'll have the variable lines containing your csv data.